# Add Object ( Class ) a array in PHP, does not recognize the type of object

Tags: php, arrays, class

I've the next classes and interfaces

```php
namespace includ\views;
interface IView 
{
    public function getContenido( );
    public function imprimirContenido( );
}
```

```php
namespace includ\views;

require_once ('IView.php' );
use includ\views\IView as IView;

interface IMenu extends IView
{

    public  function getTipo();
   public function __clone();
}
```

```php
namespace includ\views;

require ('IMenu.php');
use includ\views\IMenu;

class MenuAdministrador implements IMenu
{
  ...
}
```

and make a array

```php
 require_once ( 'menu/MenuAdministrador.php' );

 $menus=array();
 $menus[] = new includ\views\MenuAdministrador();
  //or other way
 //array_push(  $menus, new includ\views\MenuAdministrador() );
```

but, Im try to check the type of class, I make some like :

```
 var_dump($menus[0] instanceof IMenu );
```

the answer is:

```
 bool(false)
```

which is the best way to add a Object (class ) to array?

Comment: That should [work](http://3v4l.org/B4Kja) just fine. Post the entire code?

Comment: Nope, that [works too](http://3v4l.org/GM4MO). More code?

Comment: @One Trick Pony it is enough code. you missed the namespaces

Answer (score 0):

It's a namespace problem. You have to `use Includ\views\IMenu` first or better use the fully qualified class name with `instanceof`.